# Is the dash '–' between words indispensable?

Tags: grammar

In [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hard-and-fast) and [the Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/hard%20and%20fast), "hard-and-fast" has two dashes in it.

In [the Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hard-and-fast), it doesn't.

In formal settings, like research papers, is the dash '–' indispensable?

Comment: The [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hard_and_fast) (Oxford) dictionary also does not have it, so draw your own conclusions. Note that the '-' dash used to join words is called a [**hyphen**](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/hyphen). The ones used to separate are called – **en dash** and—[**em dash**](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/dash-and-em-dash). Perhaps it is just a matter of style. Personally I don't like em dashes. I think they look ugly and old-fashioned.

Comment: (1) *It was a **hard-and-fast** rule.* (2) *The rule was **hard and fast**.* Typically, hyphens are used if the adjectival phrase appears before a noun, but omitted if it appears after a noun. So, it depends greatly on context.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the **-** you mean in **"hard-and-fast"** is a **hyphen**, not a **dash**. So what's the difference between hyphens and dashes?

## Hyphens

Generally, hyphens are used to join two words or parts of words together while avoiding confusion or ambiguity.

Example:

> - run-down
> - up-to-date

There are some cases where hyphens preserve written clarity such as where there are letter collisions, where a prefix is added, or in family relations. Many words that have been hyphenated in the past have since dropped the hyphen and become a single word (email, nowadays).

Example:

> - co-operate
> - anti-nuclear
> - post-colonial

## Dashes

Dashes can be used to add parenthetical statements or comments in much the same way as you would use brackets. In formal writing you should use the bracket rather than the dash as a dash is considered less formal. Dashes can be used to create emphasis in a sentence.

Example:

> - You may think she is a liar - she isn't.
> - She might come to the party - you'll never know.

Ok, let's go back to your question. Are the hyphens between words indispensable? In your example, yes. It depends on where you use it. If the phrase appears before a noun, you'll need a hyphen, by contrast, if it appears after a noun, it can be omitted.

## Attribution

https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/hyphens-and-dashes/